# Change Lead status when assigned by Omni-Channel

Tags: leads, omnichannel

I would like to have the Lead Status change to "Assessment" when the Lead is assigned to an agent via Omni-Channel. I've tried using Process Builder and tried creating a Flow but haven't been able to achieve the desired result. Currently when the Lead is assigned to the agent the status remains "New".

The reason for this change is that I want to save the agents a "click" so they don't need to manually change the Lead Status to "Assessment" while they are assessing the Lead. The agent won't be assigned a new lead until the Lead Status is changed to "Working" (the 3rd stage in the lead process).

I'm not a developer but I do have access to one if this can't be done with configuration.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

For automation against Omni-Channel routing processes, consider creating auto-launched processes on AgentWork and PendingServiceRouting records. [AgentWork](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api.meta/api/sforce_api_objects_agentwork.htm) records are generated when work items are assigned to agents through queue, skill, or external routing. [PendingServiceRouting](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api.meta/api/sforce_api_objects_pendingservicerouting.htm) records are created when a work item is waiting to be routed to an agent.

Lightning Flows can be configured to launch on AgentWork events, which sounds like the right use case for you. Since AgentWork is an object that handles assigned work for all objects, I'd recommend creating a condition in the Flow to only run if the work item routed is a Lead. You could check this with a filter on the object prefix (`00Q` for Leads) and checking the status of the AgentWork to ensure it is opened by an agent (status: Opened).

From there, you can retrieve the Lead through the `WorkItemID` field and do whatever you need.